# Regex Remove link to another domain

Tags: php, regex

I receive a text formatted as html. I want to restrict anchor tag's urls to be only from my domain replacing the old links with "xxx" (or smth' else).
Input: "`<a href='otherdomain'>text</a>`"
Output:  "xxx"
I am using regexp to achieve this though I'm kind of stuck here:

```
$pattern ='/<a.*href=[\'|\"]http.?:\/\/[^mydomain.*\"\']*[\'|\"].*<\/a>/i';
$replace ='xxx';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: If it's user-input you want to cleanse, then you will also have to deal with absent attribute quotes or HTML entity masquerading. A regex will thus only catch the common cases; it's not suitable as reliable filter. (Without inordinate effort that is.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: @Gordon: I think it won't be easy to parse it as I receive the <a> tag  as a part of a string that already passed a filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `[^mydomain.*\"\']` you are saying "match any character except a literal 'm', 'y', 'd', 'o', ..., '.', '*', etc.

Try something like:

```
#<a [^>]*\bhref=(['"])http.?://((?!mydomain)[^'"])+\1 *>.*?</a>#i
```

Notes:

- I turned your `a.*href` to `a [^>]*\bhref` to make sure that the 'a' and 'href' are whole words and that the regex doesn't match over multiple tags.
- I changed the regex delimiter character to '#' instead of '/' so you don't have to escape the `/` any more
- Note the `((?!mydomain)[^'"])+`. This means "match [^'"]+ that isn't mydomain". The `(?!` is called a *negative look-ahead*.
- Note the `\1`. This makes sure that the closing quote mark for the URL is the same as the opening quote mark (see hwo the first set of brackets captures the `['"]`?). You'd probably be fine without it if you prefered.

For PHP (updated because I always mix up when backslashes need to be escaped in PHP -- see @GlitchMr's comment below):

```
$pattern = '#<a [^>]*\bhref=([\'"])http.?://((?!mydomain)[^\'"])+\1 *>.*?</a>#i';
```

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?3001s), where you can tweak it to your purposes.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. Could you please explain how you achieve matching of characters before and after mydomain? Like "sub.mydomain.com/page1"?

Comment: If you try changing one of the URLs to "sub.mydomain.com/page1" in the link to the interactive example I posted, you will see that that is also not matched. Or do you *want* to match 'sub.mydomain.com/page1' but not 'mydomain.com' ?

Comment: You don't need to escape backslashes in PHP, unless those escape backslashes. In single-quotes, only ``\\`` and ``\'`` are interpreted. So, if your regular expression looks like `'/^\s*$/'`, PHP sends `/^\s*$/` to regexp engine, because ``\`` doesn't escape ``\`` or `'`. The only character that is problematic when using regexp is ``\`` itself, for it you have to use ``\\\\``. PHP converts ``\\\\`` to ``\\``, and regexp engine itself converts it to ``\``. As for ``\'``, `'` is normal literal character in regexp, so PHP can safely send it without backslash to regexp engine.

Comment: Ahh thanks @GlitchMr -- I always get these confused (am used to python's `r"whateveryoulike"` format)

Comment: Instead of "http.?://" would it not much better "[a-z]+://"? Here are more schemas as "http://" or "https://". Like "ftp://" thats too a external request and maybe more.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a part of the code I'm using. It's using a user function to change the text dug out by the regex. Good luck :)

```
class RedirectLinks {
    /**
     * Callback used by convert_external_links_to_internal on each url found
     *
     * @param array $matches
     * @return string
     */
    public static function urlMatchCallback($matches)
    {
        if (stripos($matches[1], 'http://') === false ||
            stripos($matches[1], 'example.com') !== false
            ) {
            return $matches[0]; // do not modify
        }
        // encrypt url for redirection          
        $sURL = $matches[1];
        return "href=\"#\" onclick=\"showmessage('$sURL');\"";
    }

    /**
     * Converts external links in text to internal ones
     *
     * @param string $str - text
     * @return the processed text
     */
    public static function convertExternalLinksToInternal($str) {
        // convert external links to internal redirections
        $str = preg_replace_callback("/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/is", 'RedirectLinks::urlMatchCallback', $str);

        return $str;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Albeit that's no reason not to explain something.)

If you want to match 'anything but' then you usually want to use an assertion; a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.google.com/search?q=negative%20lookahead%20assertion) in your case:

```
 (?!mydomain\.com).*?
```

This will match `.*?` anything, but the disallowed value which precedes it.

Also take note that:

- It should be `[\"\']` and not `[\'|\"]`. The alternative sign has no meaning in character classes.
- `.*` should usually be `.*?` to not match too broadly.
- And `[^>]*` is the common idiom to match within tags.
- You can use other delimiters `#<a...*>#i` in place of `/` to avoid escaping.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is the character-in-set operator.  Your pattern would be a lot more understandable as

```
$pattern ='!<a\s.*?\shref\s*=\s*([\'"])https?:://mydomain.*?\1.*?</a>!is';
```

Note:

- I've whitespace delimited the tokens
- swapped the regexp quoting char to avoid the `\/`
- Use a back reference to match the quotes.